# Embed PHP contact us form into html document

Tags: php, html

I have a html document and I want to embed a PHP contact form into the page. So far I have this, which I though should call the script to the page. But at the moment nothing is displaying, not sure what I've done wrong?

```
<section>
    <header class="major">
        <h2>Mini Case studies</h2>
    </header>
    <p>If you'd like to learn more, why not download the full case study. Just complete the details below.</p>
    <iframe src="http://crea8tion.com/PP/contactus/form.php"></iframe>
    <footer>

    </footer>
</section>
```

Form.php code is as follows

```
> <?php
> 
> define('EMAIL_FOR_REPORTS', 'dano_w@hotmail.com');
> define('RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE_KEY', '@privatekey@'); define('FINISH_URI',
> 'Thank you for your interest. Click here to download the file.');
> define('FINISH_ACTION', 'redirect'); define('FINISH_MESSAGE', 'Thanks
> for filling out my form!
> http://online.wsj.com/public/resources/documents/Reprint_Samples.pdf');
> define('UPLOAD_ALLOWED_FILE_TYPES', 'doc, docx, xls, csv, txt, rtf,
> html, zip, jpg, jpeg, png, gif');
> 
> require_once str_replace('\\', '/', __DIR__) . '/handler.php';
> 
> ?>
> 
> <?php if (frmd_message()): ?> <link rel="stylesheet"
> href="<?=dirname($form_path)?>/formoid-default-skyblue.css"
> type="text/css" /> <span class="alert
> alert-success"><?=FINISH_MESSAGE;?></span> <?php else: ?> <!-- Start
> Formoid form--> <link rel="stylesheet"
> href="<?=dirname($form_path)?>/formoid-default-skyblue.css"
> type="text/css" /> <script type="text/javascript"
> src="<?=dirname($form_path)?>/jquery.min.js"></script> <form
> class="formoid-default-skyblue"
> style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;font-family:'Open
> Sans','Helvetica
> Neue','Helvetica',Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;color:#666666;max-width:250px;min-width:150px"
> method="post"><div class="title"><h2>Please complete the below to
> access the download</h2></div>    <div class="element-input" 
> <?frmd_add_class("input")?>><label class="title">Full
> Name</label><input class="large" type="text" name="input" /></div>
>   <div class="element-email"  <?frmd_add_class("email")?>><label
> class="title">Email</label><input class="large" type="email"
> name="email" value="" /></div>
> 
> <div class="submit"><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></div></form>
> <script type="text/javascript"
> src="<?=dirname($form_path)?>/formoid-default-skyblue.js"></script>
> 
> <!-- Stop Formoid form--> <?php endif; ?>
> 
> <?php frmd_end_form(); ?>
```

Comment: http://crea8tion.com/PP/contactus/form.php i go through it and it's blank

Comment: There is an error in your PHP code that is causing the script to die.

Check your logs...

Comment: Nathan, I'm not so strong on php. Are you able to help with where the issue is failing? @NathanM

Comment: Absolutely, but I'll need to see the PHP code.

Comment: Thks, I've added the form.php code to the question above. Is there anything else you need? @NathanM

Comment: Do you have access to the server logs? There is usually an error_log file in the public_html/ root directory.  I can't really make sense of this but I would make sure that all of the necessary libraries are present... this is a bit jumbled, it's hard to read.  I take it that this code came to you from elsewhere?

Comment: Nothing that I can see, sorry. No worries, I'll scrap this approach and try and find another way of doing it.

Comment: I did notice one error: where it says <?frmd_add_class("input")?> should be <?=frmd_add_class("input")?>

Comment: just write `error_reporting('E_ALL');` and `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` At top of page. you will get errors, but remove these lines when site is live

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this off. I actually used a different solution in the end. Its a pre built offering found here

http://codecanyon.net/item/contact-form-generator-form-builder/1719810?ref=topstudio

This solutions met all of my requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I used [this form](http://codecanyon.net/item/inception-responsive-form-generator-irfgenerator/7632886?ref=bcstatic). The best part is this generator also has responsive feature.

Comment: While this answer is pretty good, in the future, try to add a more complete answer. In this case you could have added the features and etc of the script to which you pointed. Also you should point out, why is it better than the accepted answer.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.